# Getting KeyError when removing element in set even though element is in set?

Tags: python, set, keyerror

Hello I've started using python fairly recently. I'm having so much trouble with this one segment of my code that gives me a keyerror when I try to remove an element from my set:

tiles.remove(m)
KeyError: 'B9'

EDIT: I forgot to mention that the m value changes everytime I call another function before the for loop. Also in the fc function, if it is false the function makes sure to add the tile back into the set tiles.add(m)

Researching online it says a keyerror only occurs when the element is not in the set but....right before I remove the element, I check to see that it is in the set and it is.

```
m = findMRV() 

if checkEmpty(board, m) == False:
    backtrack(board)     

for d in domain[m].copy():
    if checkValid(board, m[0], m[1], d ): 
        if m in tiles:
            print(str(m)+"HELLO3")
        tiles.remove(m) 
        board[m] = d

    if(fc(board, m[0], m1], d) == False):
        continue
```

the checkValid function just returns true or false and doesn't change m. I want m to be removed from the set that contains only empty tiles but I keep receiving a keyerror and I can't seem to figure out what the issue could be or where else it could be coming from.

Comment: I'm not sure what part of the code confirms that `B9` is in the set

Comment: I thought it was the print statement but yes I realized....that's silly because the tile could be removed in the next iteration in the for loop. I guess there might be something wrong with the fc implementation because it is supposed to add the tile back into the set if false and then continue the iteration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a loop

```
for d in domain[m].copy():
```

where you are trying to `tiles.remove(m)` in every iteration. After it's removed in the first iteration, the dictionary won't have the key any more and you would get a keyerror in subsequent iterations.

Comment: thank you I didn't think of that....but i forgot to include a line of code fc function which is supposed to add the tile back into the set if it returns false and then continue with the for loop.

Answer (score 1):

The ‘remove’ statement needs to be included in the ‘if’ statement, otherwise it is never prevented.